# Flutter Accessing to a Class Properity

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a pages list:

```
List<Widget> pagesList = [
PlayingPage(),
SongsPage(),
RadioPage(),
PlaylistsPage(),
FavoritesPage(),
SettingsPage(),
];
```

They are on another dart file,
I am accessing them like:

```
pagesList[index]
```

But I can't access their properties, like:

```
pagesList[index].pageName
```

How can I do it?

Comment: `pagesList[index]` pointing as widget, I might prefer creating map instead

Comment: But how can I do it? I don't understand.

Comment: The `Widget` class does not have a `pageName` member.  If the elements of your `List` all have such a member, they should derive from a common base interface, and your `List` should use that as the element type instead of `Widget`.

Comment: The list's type is dynamic since these pages are made of stateful widgets. Every page's type is its name. So it's not working either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Map for this.

```dart
final Map<String, Widget> pages = {
  'Playing': PlayingPage(),
  'Songs': SongsPage(),
  'Radio': RadioPage(),
  'Playlists': PlaylistsPage(),
  'Favorites': FavoritesPage(),
  'Settings': SettingsPage(),
};
```

You can use `pages.keys` for page names(`.toList()` if you like to have list). To use page you can use like `pages['Playing']!`(prefer null check).

Just like the `int index` you can use here `pageKey = pages.keys.elementAt(index)`

Also you can play with extension if you like

```dart
extension PageName on Widget {
  get pageName {
    if (this is PlayingPage) return 'Playing';
    if (this is SongsPage) return 'Songs';
    if (this is RadioPage) return 'Radio';
    ....
    else return runtimeType.toString();

  }
}
```

Comment: This is not quite what I want. I want to pass data between pages somehow. Like I have a bunch of static properties and I want to pass them to another class. Should I use constructors? But I don't know how to use it for this job.

Comment: *I want to pass data between pages somehow.* Perhaps you should use state-mangement solution like riverpod/bloc for this

Comment: I think it's a need. Thanks for your helps.